# NPM 7 Workspaces installing multiple versions of react

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-workspaces

We have a mono-repo that I'm migrating to npm 7's workspaces.

Current folder org:

```
\React
  - package.json (defines workspaces for \apps and \packages)
  \apps
    \someApp
      - React 17.0.1 (Dependency)
    \otherApp
  \packages
    \component-library
      - React 16.14.0 || 17.0.0 (Peer)
      - Storybook (6.1)
      - Storybook MUI Add On
    \framework
      - React 16.14.0 || 17.0.0 (Peer)
```

Running `npm ci` in the React folder installs React 16.14 in the \React\node_modules and 17.0.0 in \React\apps\someApp\node_modules.  When trying to run the app we get the expected hook error due to multiple versions being installed.  But I can't find anything that is *explicitly* requiring React 16.14?

Comment: I am also facing the exact same issue issue with npm 7 workspaces.

Comment: inside my `packages/component-library` folder, i tried to `npm link ../../node_modules/react`. It threw an error showing `npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"15.x || 16.x || 16.4.0-alpha.0911da3" from @reach/router@1.3.4`

Looks like storybook requires `@react/router` which uses `react 16.14`

Comment: Did abit more googling, looks like its an open issue https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/14119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue in the question looks like it may have been one of the many arborist bugs in early(ish) versions of NPM 7 - in NPM 8 and beyond, it should see that React 17 is supported by everything, and should therefore choose that.

---

For anyone with similar issues with more recent versions of NPM - in NPM >=8.3.0 you can use [`overrides`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) to force a particular version.

Important notes:

1. `overrides` may only be set in the repo's root `package.json`, not individual workspace `package.json` files.
2. You might need to flush node_modules and package-lock.json after adding overrides (hopefully fixed soon by the [fix to this issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4232#event-6321468104))
3. It's your responsibility to ensure that the overrides you apply don't break things: *many* packages with a `"react": "^16.x.x"` dependency are in reality compatible with React 17 and just haven't been updated, but not *all*; some may be legitimately not compatible with React 17. Be careful and look for issues on the repos of the packages whose `"^16.x.x"` dependencies you are overriding. There may even be a new version or alternative you can apply that does directly support React 17.
4. You may also need to override `react-dom` as well as `react` to ensure the two can't get out of sync.

Something like this should work in a root `package.json`:

```json
  "overrides": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using webpack, and your configuration was semi-based on create-react-app, you can tweak the modules paths, at least this works for me:

```
          modules: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules'), 'node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(modules.additionalModulePaths || []),
```

assuming your webpack.config.js is in apps/someapp/config directory